# R: How to expand date intervals to single dates

Tags: r

I have a dataset about start and end dates, and I want to expand them to consecutive dates in rows. The dataset looks like this (df1):

```
id   deg     from             to
1     1      2010-03-01       2010-03-05
1     1      2010-03-20       2010-03-25
1     2      2010-06-01       2010-06-05
```

And this is the result I want (df2):

```
id   deg     date            
1     1      2010-03-01       
1     1      2010-03-02       
1     1      2010-03-03
1     1      2010-03-04
1     1      2010-03-05
1     1      2010-03-20 
1     1      2010-03-21 
1     1      2010-03-22 
1     1      2010-03-23
1     1      2010-03-24
1     1      2010-03-25       
1     2      2010-06-01  
1     2      2010-06-02 
1     2      2010-06-03 
1     2      2010-06-04 
1     2      2010-06-05
```

Here's the different codes I've tried:

```
df2 = df1 %>%
  mutate(id= 1:nrow(.)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do(data.frame(id=.$id, date=seq.Date(.$from, .$to, by="days")))
```

But it keeps showing the error: wrong sign in 'by' argument

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Do you have `Date` class?

Comment: Your code seems to work. Did you convert the `from` and `to` columns to a date?

Comment: @cazman yea, I did that in data import part

Comment: Then, it is working fine for me.  You need to change the `mutate(id= row_number())`

Comment: Hi all, thank you very much for the solutions. I just found out the reason. In the original dataset, there are some rows that have their from to to dates switched, so the end date is earlier than the start date, and that gives the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(new = list(seq(as.Date(from), as.Date(to), by = 1))) %>% 
  select(id, deg, new) %>% 
  unnest()
```

This gives us:

```
# A tibble: 16 x 3
      id   deg new       
   <int> <int> <date>    
 1     1     1 2010-03-01
 2     1     1 2010-03-02
 3     1     1 2010-03-03
 4     1     1 2010-03-04
 5     1     1 2010-03-05
 6     1     1 2010-03-20
 7     1     1 2010-03-21
 8     1     1 2010-03-22
 9     1     1 2010-03-23
10     1     1 2010-03-24
11     1     1 2010-03-25
12     1     2 2010-06-01
13     1     2 2010-06-02
14     1     2 2010-06-03
15     1     2 2010-06-04
16     1     2 2010-06-05
```

Data:

```
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L), deg = c(1L, 1L, 2L), from = structure(c(14669L, 
14688L, 14761L), class = c("IDate", "Date")), to = structure(c(14673L, 
14693L, 14765L), class = c("IDate", "Date"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001e0b8dc1ef0>, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

We may do this in `summarise` without the need to use `do`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    rowwise %>%
    summarise(id, deg = deg, date = seq(from, to, by = 1), .groups = "drop")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 16 x 3
      id   deg date      
   <int> <int> <date>    
 1     1     1 2010-03-01
 2     1     1 2010-03-02
 3     1     1 2010-03-03
 4     1     1 2010-03-04
 5     1     1 2010-03-05
 6     1     1 2010-03-20
 7     1     1 2010-03-21
 8     1     1 2010-03-22
 9     1     1 2010-03-23
10     1     1 2010-03-24
11     1     1 2010-03-25
12     1     2 2010-06-01
13     1     2 2010-06-02
14     1     2 2010-06-03
15     1     2 2010-06-04
16     1     2 2010-06-05
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L), deg = c(1L, 1L, 2L), from = structure(c(14669, 
14688, 14761), class = "Date"), to = structure(c(14673, 14693, 
14765), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```